# Can I decrease ping without fibre optic cable?

Tags: ping

I play CS:GO, and I get a ping of around around 280-350 ms which is very high. My friend suggested that I get a fibre optic connection, but my parents did not agree to it.

Is there any way I can reduce my latency? They usually kick out players with a latency above 200 ms, and that's my main issue. I don't know if there is any script, program, or manual fix.

Please help me reduce my latency.

Comment: ping to where exactly? to a server on the other side of the world, or to your ISP, or to your home router? First find where the problem actually is (use tracert/traceroute/mtr/WinMTR/pathping).

Comment: You have to include a lot more detail into your question. Where is the connection lagging, what is your current internet plan, where is the server located etc. etc. Also include what you already tried to do. Please also review http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask. Good questions get good answers, bad questions get bad or no answers.

Comment: @grawity On speedtest.net im getting ping 41ms

Comment: @AliveColdJuan your ping to speedtest is fine so the problem is somewhere between you and the remote server beyond your local connection to the internet. Try playing on more geographically local servers. There is nothing you are going to be able to do to improve this as you have no control of the infrastructure that is beyond your home.

Comment: Using a fiber to the house connection ( i.e. Verizon FIOS ) won't by default decrease your ping.  Ping is latency of the connection which has no little to do with the amount of bandwidth you have.  You can have a very low ping on a very fow bandwidth connection.

Comment: @AliveColdJuan: Even speedtest.net has a hundred servers around the world. Did it use the one in the same city or one in another country? You'd need to test multiple destination to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the geographical server location to something closer or changing the hardware you use to connect to the Internet can lower your Latency and therefore reduce Lag.

**PING** is a tool that measures the Round Trip Time (**RTT**) of data to reach the destination and then return.  It is measured as **Latency** in ms.  You reported 280-350ms of Latency.  Latency is a component of **Lag**, which is the perceived performance degradation.  Packet loss is the other common contributor to Lag.

There are two major components to Latency.

Data travels over the wire/fiber at roughly 120 miles per millisecond (ms).  Thus for every 60 miles between you and the destination, you can expect 1 additional ms in a PING test.  Keep in mind this is the distance the data has to travel, not direct distance or way of the crow.

Devices along the way also contribute to the overall Latency.  Cable modems have been reported to add 5-40ms and DLS modems around 10-70ms.  Wireless APs and routers will contribute as well.  Each additional device such as another firewall, router or switch (**hops**) between you and the destination will add to the overall latency as well.  Expect older networking gear to add additional latency.  So could a miscalibrated or misconfigured cable modem.

Reference:
https://www.pingman.com/kb/42

All wireless connections will likely incur some degree of Packet Loss due to the nature of the medium and additional Latency due to protocol overhead.

Many of these factors that contribute to Latency are outside of your ability to change.

It is true that Fiber connections typically have fewer hops between you and the Internet.  It also true that these hops can different than the path of hops from a DSL or cable modem.  The different path could have lower Latency per hop.

*HOWEVER*, fiber connectivity is not always guaranteed to lower latency and has an additional added cost of service.

In a non-ideal situation, a congested link could contribute to Latency, but the relation is not as direct as one might think.  Quality of Service (QoS) and TCP Congestion Avoidance measures could kick in. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2001

The result is that packets are queued or dropped.  This can happen on either end of a congested link.  In a non-congested link, bandwidth has zero effect on Latency.

I recommend changing the geographical location of the servers to which you are connecting.  I also recommend bypassing the hops in your home by directly connecting to your DSL or cable modem.  Check with your ISP to verify that your DSL or cable modem is operating as expected.  Finally replace, eliminate or bypass the hops that are contributing the most latency in your home.  When testing, do so when there is little additional traffic on your network to avoid seeing the effects of network congestion.

Comment: Ye i think its a server out of my country since i dont have a steam bought game i cant find servers in my country

Comment: Data can only move so fast through fiber or copper.  Can't change physics.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don’t have bufferbloat.

Many home network middleboxes (broadband modems, home gateway routers, Wi-Fi APs, etc) have a well-known bug called bufferbloat that spikes latency when congestion happens. That is, they don’t drop or ECN-mark packets when congestion happens, so they allow long queues of frame buffers to build up and never drain, which just adds latency with no benefit.

Run http://speedtest.dslreports.com/ when you see that high ping RTT while playing your game, and see what bufferbloat grade it gives you. Note that this is a very different speed test tool than the popular speedtest.net.

If you have bufferbloat, you need to run a router with a packet scheduler that targets low latency, such as FQ-CoDel (available in OpenWrt, DD-WRT, etc.). You also need to run some traffic shaping that makes this router an ever-so-slight bottleneck on your network, so it gets a chance to employ bufferbloat countermeasures before buffer queues start bloating up on other network middleboxes in your path.

This tuning can be tricky to optimize. If you’d like a turn-key solution, look at the IQrouter from EvenRoute.com. I haven’t used one so I can’t vouch for it, but it seems to be designed specifically to solve bufferbloat as I’ve described.

Answer (score 0):

All good answers.  However, just remember that you could be running 10 gigabit speeds on your local network, but if you are only paying for CenturyLinks 7 megabit down and 2 megabit up, that could be your problem. Especially if you have parents or siblings who are also trying to use up the bandwidth by playing games or streaming video.

I would ask your parents what internet package you have, and from what provider. Then if you do in fact have slow internet, look into other options. If its available in your area, I would recommend Charter's 100 megabit down, 5 megabit up option for $60 per month.

Another source of your latency could be the type of internet you have. If your internet uses a satellite connection like Dish, that alone could add a ton of latency especially on a cloudy day.

Comment: Having additional bandwidth can help with Jitter, which can reduce perceived Lag but will not have an appreciable effect on Latency.  If you have a road and add more lanes, it can carry more cars and more loads of cargo (data bearer traffic) but it won't change the speed limit.

Comment: Your missing the point though. I'm saying that if he has a very low bandwidth internet connection and someone else is using a lot of it then yes this could be the source of the latency. My friend will hit 300 ping just because he and his brother are playing games at the same time or his wife gets on Netflix or something.

Comment: A congested link can result in QoS and TCP Congestion Avoidance measures to kick in which could result in packet queuing or packet loss and therefore higher latency.  

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2001

This is still packet loss or latency incurred at a hop and more detail than intended for the original post.  Additional bandwidth can reduce congestion.  However, you still are incorrectly relating total available bandwidth and how it affects latency.

Comment: I will edit my post to include information relating to the affects of a congested link.

Comment: Low bandwidth does not always result in high latency.  Most often a connection ls latency has nothing to do with a connection bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed sharing a simple DSL connection with a household, something like CFOSSPEED (http://www.cfos.de/en/download/download.htm) can help, when installed on all the networked PCs to assign priorities and get the most of that connection.

If you bad ping is due to network congestion on your side, that can help greatly. That's what I'm using to make sure my VoIP is always crystal clear when I'm using other stuff (gaming, serving files, etc.) or downloading heavy stuff.

Comment: Why this application in particular? Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)

Comment: I was only mentioning this one application as an example ("something like", not "use that") as I have been now using it for more than 10 years and have been perfectly happy with it. It does install a system-level driver which does QoS on your connection. I don't see it as any less valid thn recommending to use a router and set your QoS there (other post here).